# Azure DevOps Portfolio plans (beta) too slow and lacks significant features

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

Portfolio Plans (Beta) roadmapping tool in ADO is not a full-featured tool and lacks significant features that are needed to effectively create and manage product roadmaps. Are there any alternative extensions?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that there is no such full-featured tool could meet your requirements.

For alternative tool, I suggest that you could try to use the Azure DevOps New Build-in feature: [Delivery Plans 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/plans/review-team-plans?view=azure-devops).

[image]

This tool don't need to install any extensions. And the Azure DevOps Team will also update this tool regularly according to the needs of users.

If you have any further requirements, I suggest that you could submit the feature feedback in the following site: [Feature feedback](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?from=email&viewtype=all&space=21&entry=suggestion).

On the other hand, there are some similar extensions in the marketplace.

For example: [Planner Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=InnotechStrategies.custom-planner) , [Portfolio++](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=itrellis.portfolio-plus-plus)

But they still don't have full features.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Portfolio++.  It provides cross-project roadmaps, Epic/Feature Timeline - as well as Boards work-item quality assurance (Epic status), and the Pro version offers dependencies, milestones, and the ability to sort the order of the epics in the Roadmap.